# Etiquette of asking an old question again

Tags: discussion, etiquette

Don't know if this is the right place to ask, but I have a question that was asked by someone else back in 2015 [How to bulk renew membership](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/424/how-to-bulk-renew-membership). There have been some suggestions that would not be answers in my case. I added a comment to see if the original person who asked had found a comment, but he hasn't responded. Possibly not still active. I don't think that my comment would bring it to anyone else's attention. Is it reasonable to ask the question again? I think its of reasonably wide interest.

Comment: Related: [How do I get attention for one of my own questions without a good answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046) (while the title stated "my own questions", the answer can be applied by any users. That said, don't post the same question because it will just be closed as a dupe to the older question)

Answer (score 3):

You can ask a similar question providing you reference the old question and make it clear why you are asking again.

Eg:

- "This similar question (xxx) was asked previously but it does not address my situation because ..."
- "This question (xxx) was asked in 2015. Are there any new ways to solve this problem?"